# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileData' of undefined on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Just Started Learning Reactjs Tried This Code To Make Simple Hobby list Which is Going to rendered From Array With Name And Image  But Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileData' of undefined on Reactjs

```js
var DATA = {
    name: 'John Smith',
    imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/',
    hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
}
//main app component
var App = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
          <div>
              <Profile
                  name={this.props.profileData.name}
                  imgURL={this.prpos.profileData.imgURL}
                  />
              <Hobby
                 hobbyList = {this.props.profileData.hobbyList}
                  />
          </div>
        );
    }
});
//profile component
var Profile = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
        <div>
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <img src={this.props.imgURL}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
var Hobby = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        var hobbies = this.props.hobbyList.map(function(hobby,index){
            return (<li key={index}>{hobbies}</li>);
        });
        <div>
            <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
            <ul>{hobbies}</ul>
        </div>
    }
});
//render method
ReactDOM.render(
    <App profileData={DATA}/>,
    document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React For EveryOne Tutorial</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="demo.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes

1. In `App` component there is typo, should be `this.props` instead of `this.prpos`

   ```
   this.prpos.profileData.imgURL
        ^^^^^
   ```
2. Add `return` statement in `Hobby` component

   ```
   return <div>
      <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
       <ul>{hobbies}</ul>
   </div>
   ```
3. In `Hobby` component in `.map`, you should use `hobby` variable instead of `hobbies`

   ```
   return (<li key={index}>{hobby}</li>);
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32343/)

Comment: @user5323957 3rd suggestion is very simple - you have `.map` loop, and you should use variable `hobby` that in callback,  in each iteration you get one item which you need show in `<li>`. When you use `hobbies` it will be empty list because `hobbies` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the return statement in Hobby component and a typo in `this.prpos.profileData.imgURL` with `this.prpos` instead of `this.props`:

```
var DATA = {
    name: 'John Smith',
    imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/',
    hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
}
//main app component
var App = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
          <div>
              <Profile
                  name={this.props.profileData.name}
                  imgURL={this.props.profileData.imgURL}
                  />
              <Hobby
                 hobbyList = {this.props.profileData.hobbyList}
                  />
          </div>
        );
    }
});
//profile component
var Profile = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
        <div>
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <img src={this.props.imgURL}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
var Hobby = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        var hobbies = this.props.hobbyList.map(function(hobby,index){
            return (<li key={index}>{hobbies}</li>);
        });
        return (
          <div>
              <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
              <ul>{hobbies}</ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
});
//render method
ReactDOM.render(
    <App profileData={DATA}/>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byoigres/0xrbm2nm/2/)

Comment: yes that was also the case but now also getting same error